# JQuery - Get value after delimiter alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've already searched this up before and tried using both `pop()` and `lastIndexOf` but it doesn't work well on looped dropdown.

Is there any alternative to getting the value after a delimiter, one that does not remove it from the list?

Here's my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#VehicleID').change(function () {
            var vehdrv = ($('#VehicleID :selected').val());
            var drvid = vehdrv.split("_").pop();
            var vehid = vehdrv.split("_")[0];

            $('#VehicleID :selected').val(vehid);
            //alert($('#VehicleID :selected').val());

            if (drvid > 0) {
                $('#DriverID').find("option").show().not("option[value*='" + drvid + "']").hide();

                $("#DriverID").val(drvid);

                //$("#DriverID").val(
                //$("#DriverID").find("option:visible:first").val())
            }

            else {
                $("#DriverID").find("option").show();

                $("#DriverID").val(
   $("#DriverID").find("option:visible:first").val())
            }
        }).trigger("change");
    })
```

My Dropdowns from the controller:

```
public ActionResult ReserveInitial()
    {
        ViewBag.VehicleID = db.Vehicles.Where(item => item.IsReserved == false).Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.VehicleID.ToString() + "_" + a.DriverID.ToString(),
            Text = a.VehicleMake + " - " + a.PlateNumber,
        });

        ViewBag.DriverID = db.Drivers.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DriverID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DriverLastName + ", " + a.DriverFirstName
        });


        return View();
    }
```

**EDIT**
This is how the string would look like if the VehicleID is linked to a Driver:
"14_5"

if the VehicleID is not associated with a Driver it would look like this:
"15_0"

Comment: When posting a question about finding element(s) in a string, please add in a couple of examples of what the original elements look like, for instance "xxx_yyy_zzz" or something. It is hard to deduce from your code what you expect the strings to look like.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Thanks for the advice, added how the string would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parts = vehdrv.split("_");
var drvid = parts[1];
var vehid = parts[0];
```

Comment: Still the same result, it removes the drvid value after the same vehid value is picked again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var vehdrv = $('#VehicleID').val().match(/[^_]+/g);
  var drvid = vehdrv[0];
  var vehid = vehdrv[1];
 
 console.log(drvid,vehid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="VehicleID" type="text" value="14_5" name="text">
```